# Laravel - What are .rnd files after installing Laravel passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

What is .rnd file that appear after installing Laravel Passport at root? Does it contain any sensitive data? Should we commit it to repo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general the `.rnd` file is a file that contains random data used for creating unique secure certificates for laravel passport.

> Next, you should run the passport:install command. **This command will create the encryption keys needed to generate secure access tokens**. ...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#installation

> When deploying Passport to your production servers for the first time, you will likely need to run the passport:keys command. This command generates the encryption keys Passport needs in order to generate access token. **The generated keys are not typically kept in source control**:
>
> `php artisan passport:keys`

https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport#deploying-passport

Comment: This answer doesnt address wether the .rnd file can be deleted or committed and wether it is sensitive or even what the purpose of the .rnd file is at all, because the generated keys are stored in different files, inside the storage directory. i assume since it is about random info used while generating keys it has something to do with not generating the same keys twice if you rerun the command. so it might be slightly sensitive. for now i am just going to delete it because it seems  unlikely to me that you generate the same keys twice. but i may be completely wrong about the purpose.